# How to reassign a sub object with a path?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reference, assign

I have an object and an array which is the path to an attribute if this one :

I want to reassign the matching attribute value with a new one.

```js
var objectToNavigate = {
    mainTest: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
    otherTests: {
        oneTest: ["item1", "item2", "item3"],
        anotherTest: ["item1", "item2"],
    }
};

var currentPath = ["otherTests", "oneTest"];

var currentObject = objectToNavigate;
currentPath.forEach(
    path => currentObject = currentObject[path]
);

const newValue = ["hello", "new", "value"];

console.log(currentObject === objectToNavigate.otherTests.oneTest) // true
currentObject = newValue;
console.log(currentObject === objectToNavigate.otherTests.oneTest) // false

console.log("currentObject : %o", currentObject); // currentObject : (3) ['hello', 'new', 'value']
console.log("objectToNavigate : %o", objectToNavigate); // objectToNavigate didn't change
```

Can someone explain me why currentObject = newValue change the reference and doesn't modify the object itself ?

How can I fix it ?

Comment: You reassign a reference to the variable without modifying the object itself.

To get what you want, you have to modify the object. e.g. push a value into the array.

What you're trying to do is change what objectToNavigate.otherTests.oneTest points to. You can do this by removing oneTest from the currentPath and then assigning newValue to currentObject.oneTest.

Comment: If I understand well I can : store currentPath.pop(), delete it, and reassign it with currentObject[popedValue] ?

Comment: As long as you are modifying the referenced object instead of assigning a new reference to the variable. By doing currentObject.oneTest = something, you are currently modifying the property oneTest of the referenced object currentObject.